# Access to database and connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql, connection-string

This is my connection string:

```
 <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

It stopped throwing exceptions, but the access to the database doesnt seem to work, cause when i answer the confirmation question, it says it is wrong and wont let me in!!

```
    <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">

  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add
   name="MyMembershipProvider"    
   type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"      
   connectionStringName="modelConnectionString"             
   minRequiredPasswordLength="1"          
   minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
   enablePasswordReset="true"
   maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"
   passwordAttemptWindow="4000"
   enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
   requiresUniqueEmail="false"
   passwordFormat="Encrypted" 
   applicationName="/WebSite10"

   />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: First check the authentication mode of Sql Server you are connecting and then let me know all the details.

Comment: did you made an aspnet user in sqlserver ?and what privileges have you given

Comment: The authentication mode is "Forms".. Unfortunately, i dont know the procedure of making aspnet user and privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a database name in the connection string - in the top one you are specifying the database file where you should be declaring the database name.

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

If you're attaching a database file to a local instance of SQL then you need to use the `AttachDbFilename` property.

Comment: Why do i need to use SQLExpress and not localserver.. the default server?.. well, i dont attach it. it is aspnetdb, which is created automatically by visual studio 2010

Comment: You don't need to use SQLExpress, that's just an example instance name. You need to specify where the server instance is for the database to be attached to.

Comment: i added your modification. now it doesnt throw an exception, it simply says the user name is not in the database. The instance is inside server explorer in visual studio. It was added by the program (VS2010) not by me

Comment: OK, the database connection is made then, now you've got enough to go on and work the rest out. That's nothing to do with the connection string, but to do with the membership provider. Look into using the WAT to manage the users for the membership provider.

Comment: Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DIMA-00AA1DA557\Dima'.  -- Thats what i tried. it doesnt give me the old exception that i stated in the question. I still cant access the database. I wonder what you provide in the connection string or do in windows configuration to be able to enter the database

Comment: There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DIMA-00AA1DA557\Dima'.  ---- Thats what i get when i go to WAT Config

Comment: That's because your database probably isn't called dbname. These are only sample properties which you need to replace with all your own information.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the membership provider: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: oooh, i right clicked the database aspnetDB in server explorer, chose modify connection, clicked test connection, the connection succeeded. i clicked---> Advance..and there were more properties:  Application name: .Net SqlClient Data Provider .. should i put this name in my membership provider..or copy more properties to put into my connection string

Comment: <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> -- that connection string doesnt throw the exception

Comment: There you go. Got there in the end. I still suggest you read up on the membership provider though.

Comment: I updated my answer above, it still makes problems. I am not sure if it is the connections string fault or the properties i have in membership provider

Comment: i am able to create new users now.. still have a problem with retrieving a password :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you not create the connection through the Visual studio server explorer. You can log into the server using the correct credentials then save the correct connection string to the config file.

There is a [microsoft knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316649)! on this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But can u see why i fail to connect to the database with one of the connection strings from above?